# Hard links in Ionic2/Angular 2 to JSON array products

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Back in Ionic 1, it was possible make hard links to products using the url and also pages. Such as `state ui-sref="tabs.list"` and `<a href="#/app/products/0">`

This would be where 0 was the first item in an array within a factory.

Is it possible to make hard links when the items are in a JSON array, without having to loop through them in a *NgIf loop. So do a direct page link to product 1 here for example?

```
    [
            { "title": "Product 1", "id": "0", "video": "video/prod1.mp4", "duration": "1 min 24 sec" },
            { "title": "Product 2", "id": "1", "video": "video/prod2.mp4", "duration": "1 min 28 sec" }
    ]
```

Also, what is the situation with state in Ionic/Angular 2? I now links can now be made direct to pages with push/pop, but wondering what to do with my functions from Ionic 1 that were based around the state.

Comment: Not sure what your previous approach was, but I would actually do a navigation push using https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavParams/ by passing the entire object. So you wouldloop the array of objects, avoid the URL thing (just add a (click) event) and bind the entire json object to the function, so that you can literally pass the object to the next view.

Comment: So if I wanted to push to that product1 in that array, what target would I need to replace in the Nav here please?
```<div class="product1" [navPush]="productListPage"><img src="../../assets/img/product1.png"></div>```

Comment: Use the [navParams] attribute.

Comment: @merch89: I would avoid the entire navpush process, I would handle the logic separately from the view: in your view, you would have something like: `<div *ngFor="let product of myProductsList"> post your data <button (click)="goToProduct(product);">Detail</button>`. Then, in your controller, you actually handle the goToProduct method and directly use NavParams to push to the next view the whole product object, so that you don't need to bother if, in the near future, you will eventually have (for some reason) to pass other data, so that you will already have it ;)